# Effective bounds on root discriminant assuming GRH?

Tags: nt.number-theory

It is known conditionally on GRH that, for all $\alpha<44.7632 \dots$, there are are only finitely many number fields $K$ satisfying $\Delta_K ^{ 1/[K:\mathbb Q]}< \alpha$.

For which $\alpha$ can we make this effective by giving an upper bound on $[K:\mathbb Q]$ for all fields satisfying $\Delta_K ^{ 1/[K:\mathbb Q]}< \alpha$, assuming GRH and maybe some other conjecture?

Comment: Presumably you've already looked at Odlyzko's survey (which has some tables at the end): http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/discriminant.survey.pdf

Comment: Just a side remark: In your opening line you write "it is known," but is the quoted result, with the constant $44.7632\ldots = 8\pi e^{\gamma}$, not conditional on GRH? If I understand correctly, the unconditional result is available for half that constant.

Comment: @Lucia: I am interested in somewhat higher values of $\alpha$.

Comment: @Vesselin thanks for pointing out that oversight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the answer is contained in one of the references in the survey Lucia mentioned. The relevant table is [here](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/unpublished/discr.bound.table1).